# Android->Settings->Security->StorageType get Value inside app

Tags: android, credentials, keystore, android-keystore

In newer versions of Android (I guess since 4.2) there is an option called "hardware-backed" and "software only". 
As Google supposes:

> Android also now supports hardware-backed storage for your KeyChain
>   credentials, providing more security by making the keys unavailable
>   for extraction. That is, once keys are in a hardware-backed key store
>   **(Secure Element, TPM, or TrustZone)**, they can be used for
>   cryptographic operations but the private key material cannot be
>   exported. Even the OS kernel cannot access this key material. While
>   not all Android-powered devices support storage on hardware, you can
>   check at runtime if hardware-backed storage is available

ephasis is mine

What I can't understand is: the  GalaxyNexus as well as the Nexus 7 have an NFC-Chip **with** Secure Element, but its storage-type is "software only". The Nexus 4 has an NFC Secure Element, and is "hardware-backed", while the Nexus 7 (2013) and the Nexus 5 don't have a NFC-Secure-Element but are still "hardware backed". I can check this manually inside the Settings-App, but Is there a way to check this inside my App?

As CommonsWare mentioned, I should provide links: 
First info that Secure Element is related to the storage-type is mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#Security):
another useful source of info was [Nelenkov's blog](http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/credential-storage-enhancements-android-43.html)

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right, that it is not exactly related. It just needs a "hardware root of trust" (which can be an NFC secure Element) which the Galaxy Nexus clearly has, but is only supporting Software Only credentials. Have a look at my edit

Comment: So, you wish to know if the storage-type is hardware backed or not?

Comment: exactly, this is what I want to find out inside my app.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you use reflection since KeyStore service is not part of the SDK >>> Obtain an `IKeystoreService` from `ServiceManager` and call the `is_hardware_backed()` method. But, as Nikolay answered below, `KeyChain#isBoundKeyAlgorithm(String)` follows the same route, calling `IKeystoreService#is_hardware_backed()` eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you actually read the blog? :) Currently 'hardware-backed' means TrustZone (TEE)-backed for all released devices. Using the embedded secure element for this is rather tricky for political reasons, and no current Android devices have a TMP. This leaves TrustZone-based TEE implementations. BTW, Galaxy Nexus also has one, but the driver is disabled in release builds. It has been there since 4.1.

To check from an app use `KeyChain.isBoundKeyAlgorithm(String algorithm)`.

Comment: Wow, Mr. Elenkov himself is answering ;). I read your blog (along all the posts about SecureElements and how to use them). This probably confused me a bit. Thanks for giving the proper answer.